# Excel VBA function to only paste what is within the print area rather than the entire sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a copy/paste vba code to transfer my financial model to a pasted version in a separate excel model and cannot figure out how to only paste what is shown within the print area. Currently it is working just fine but it pastes all data outside of the print range and shows all data that is hidden in rows/columns and not displayed.

I cannot seem to find a function or simple function to add to the already working code that would do this. I am new to VBA and unsure of the best method to add this functionality.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook, wsExhibit1 As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet, wsInputs As Worksheet, _
    wsExhibit2 As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx")
    With wb
        Set wsExhibit1 = .Sheets("Value_Summary")
        Set wsInputs = .Sheets("Inputs")
        Set wsExhibit2 = .Sheets("Calculations")
    End With

    With wbPaste
        Set wsPaste = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    With wsPaste
        wsExhibitA1.UsedRange.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
    End With

    wsInputs.Range("Selected_Calculation").Value = 1
    Do Until wsInputs.Range("Selected_Calculation").Value > wsInputs.Range("Total_Calculations").Value
        Application.Calculate
        With wbPaste
            Set wsTemp = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With
        With wsTemp
            wsExhibit2.UsedRange.Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
        End With
    wsInputs.Range("Selected_Calculation").Value = wsInputs.Range("Selected_Calculation").Value + 1
    DoEvents
    Loop
    wsInputs.Range("Selected_Calculation").Value = 1

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

I am hoping to only paste what is within the print area set within the workbook on the respective pages. Not pasting down hidden data or data outside of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Print_Area` is a named range.

```
Sheets(“SheetName”).Range(“Print_Area”).Copy
```

To avoid hidden cells:

```
Sheets(“SheetName”).Range(“Print_Area”).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: Of course, very simple answer then. Thank you for the assistance. Any tips on how to ignore hidden rows/columns in the paste?